# What does function re creation means? How bad it is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, callback

What does javascript re-create function every time when component re-render means?
I am basically referring to the following code.

This way of invoking function recreate function
`onChange={() => this.someFunction() }`

Where as this is not
`onChange={this.someFunction}`

I basically needs to understand how Javascript re create the functions or when it wont re create function.

Any explanation or reference guide will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Functions in JavaScript are just Function type objects which means they're just like other normal variables, when a component re-renders, all variables in it will be re-declared, so do those functions.

Comment: Thank Chris. That makes sense to me. But I would like to know will it has any side effects like a memory leak or something?

Answer (score 1):

your `onChange` prop needs a function which will be triggered when the user makes changes .

when you have this `onChange={() => this.someFunction()}` you are passing a function to the onChange which is correct . But now when there is a re-render we are re-creating a brand new function `() => this.someFunction()` again and assigning it to your `onchange` prop .

whereas when you have this `onChange={this.someFunction}` you have already created a class method named `someFunction` and passing it to the `onChange`.

The major difference between the 2 is that in your component which uses the inline function (`() => this.someFunction()`) your `this.props.onChange === prevProps.onChange` will always be `false` because you are creating a new function for each re-render and since function in JS are nothing but objects your reference which `onChange` holds will keep changing each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation @Shyam.  Does function re-creating on every re-render has any other side effects like a memory leak? apart from react component performance issue.